# ran npm publish without error but cannot see updated package

Tags: npm, npm-publish

I updated my version in package.json and ran "npm publish". I did not see any error and see the log "package-name prepublishOnly" in terminal. Now if I go to https://www.npmjs.com/package/, I could not see updated package. Then if I ran "npm publish" again, it gives me error as below:

```
npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 403
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! Forbidden The feed already contains the package 'package-name' at version 'X.Y.Z': 'package-name'
```

I would like to know why and if I publish the package successfully or not.

Answer (score 2):

Give it some time. Your package is probably uploaded, the webpage might not be updated immediately yet.

I thought I was seeing the same thing with my package as of 11:38AM PT on 2/28/2019, as the page of my package would show the older version. However, when searching for my package I would see the new version. Most importantly, running `npm init` and `npm install mypackage` would install the new version, which is what matters the most anyway.